# laravel relationship query twice?

Tags: php, laravel

```
//Eloquent relationship 
$customer = App\Customer::find($id); //1s query
return $orders = $customer->orders(); //2nd query

class 
public function orders() {
     return $this->hasMany('App\Order', 'customer_id')->get();
}

//Query builder, only query once
$data = DB::table('customers')
      ->select('orders.name...')
      ->leftJoin('orders', 'customers.id', '=', 'orders.customer_id')
      ->get();
```

I'm currently learning laravel, I was wondering when I use relationship to do left join query, is it will query twice?

If so which is better for performance? query builder left join can save one query which is the one I usually go with

Comment: Just a note: in your `orders` relationship method you aren't supposed to call `->get()`, just `return $this->hasMany('App\Order', 'customer_id');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Query builder is better for performance.

https://blog.sriraman.in/laravel-eloquent-vs-fluent-query-builder/

Comment: @Benjamin W noone will run 1000 queries per request in real project, so ask yourself: are you ready to loose all features and pros of Eloquent to get 1ms query instead of 2 ms query?

Comment: @AlexeyMezenin the op asked which is better for performance. He has the answer

Comment: Yes, technically it's faster. But I've just compared couple of queries and the difference between whole request execution is like 583.2 ms for query builder and 583.5 ms for Eloquent. So I'd say you don't want to look at such benchmarks when you're dealing with real app. You're selling the power of ORM, readability and maintainability for 1 ms execution time. That's my point.

Comment: I completely agree.

Answer (score 3):

I would say eloquent relations are much better because -

By Using two queries it simplifies the initialization of `eloquent` models.

If you use join queries instead, there's a chance that two columns have the same name, for example, the `id`. So, you would explicitly select the columns.

At the `PHP` side, you would then unpack the values appropriately so they can be delegated to the correct `eloquent` class. This would further increase the execution time and increase memory usage and not to mention code complexity.

Answer (score 1):

You can indeed retrieve many records at once using Query Builder (or raw SQL), but the obvious downside is that you won't have the power of using a model class because the Query Builder returns arrays. As you may already know, models aren't supposed to just help you with queries; they are useful beyond that.

And as iCode said (that replied while I was typing this), you would ask yourself: "why don't Laravel just joins columns to only do one query and then create all the models?" Well, the query itself and the logic in PHP needed for this to work would be pretty complex and it's not worth it.

Finally, when Eloquent relationships save a lot queries is when you query a bunch of `Customer` records along their `Order` records: in such case, all orders are taken with just one query.